# Evaluate integral using Fubini/Tonelli

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I need to evaluate the following integral using Fubini/Tonelli theorems:

$$\int_\mathbb{R^2} |f(x,y)| dxdy$$

where $f(x,y) = 2(x-y)e^{-(x-y)^2}$ if $x > 0$, and zero otherwise.

I can't figure out how to do it. I think I could use Fubini since $|f(x,y)| \geq 0$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$.

So: $$\int_{\mathbb{R^2}} |f(x,y)|dxdy = \int_0^{\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |2(x-y)e^{-(x-y)^2}| dy\right) dx$$

How do I continue? Or is this the wrong approach?

Edit: I forgot to mention I am allowed to use that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-z} dz = \sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: How about a substitution $x-y=z$ in the inner integral?

Comment: A small comment: Tonelli is the one you use for positive functions regardless of integrability.

Comment: Whoops! I meant Tonelli, of course. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fubini's theorem requires the integrated function to be integrable in the product space. Tonelli's theorem only requires non-negativity. The combined result is often referred to as Fubini-Tonelli. In your case, you are using the Tonelli part of the theorem.

Let $x>0$. Substituting $z=x-y$ in the inner integral gives

$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |2(x-y)e^{-(x-y)^2}| dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2|z|e^{-z^2}dz=2$$

Therefore $F(x)=2$ for every $x>0$. Thus your integral equals

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |f(x,y)| d(x,y)=\int_0^\infty 2\, dx = \infty$$

That means your function $f$ is not integrable in the product space $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don't see why $F(x)$ is equal to $C$ in that last step of the first equation. But maybe I should use what I mentioned in my edit here, somehow?

Comment: @BobM I *defined* the integral to be $C$. It is some positive constant, which can be easily calculated using integration by parts and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx=\sqrt{\pi}$, but this is not required to solve your problem. All that matters is that it is some *positive* number not dependent on anything else.

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering why does $C \not= \infty$ hold.

Comment: @BobM: First off, if it was $\infty$, the final conclusion would be the same. Nevertheless: $xe^{-x^2}$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$, it is a [rapidly decreasing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space).

Comment: I'm confused about something else then: you have substituted $x-y = z$, but in the second integral there is no $z$ but a $y$. Why is this a $y$? Or should it be $z$? In that case, I think $C$ _is_ dependant of $x$.

Comment: @BobM $y$ is a variable of integration. I could have also named it $z$, or $j$, or $\xi^{1,2,3}_{a,b,c}$. What I mean is this: $\int f(y) dy = \int f(z) dy = \int f(\xi^{1,2,3}_{a,b,c} d\xi^{1,2,3}_{a,b,c} = \cdots$.

Comment: Yes, but $C$ is still depending on $x$...

Comment: @BobM: Ok I will edit it so that you will understand. Wait.

Comment: Oh is it because the integral is on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @BobM Exactly that is the point! The substitution just translates the real axis by $x$, but then you get again the real axis!

Comment: @BobM Please consider voting the answer up as well.

Comment: I'd like to, but I need 2 reputation more... Thanks a bunch though, couldn't have done it without your help!